# Android activity-alias shows two apps in mobile menu

Tags: android, android-manifest, manifest, android-activity-alias

Hey guys I am using `activity-alias` and it shows 2 apps on device (`Google Pixel`)

Screenshot:

[image]

My CODE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication"
        tools:targetApi="34">

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myapplication.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="locale|orientation"
            android:excludeFromRecents="false"
            android:exported="false"
            android:noHistory="true" />

        <!-- activity alis -->
        <activity-alias
            android:name="com.example.myapplication.MainActivityAlias"
            android:exported="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="one 1"
            android:targetActivity="com.example.myapplication.MainActivity"
            tools:targetApi="34">

            <!-- intent filter -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias>


        <!--        <activity-alias-->
        <!--            android:name=".MainActivityAlias2"-->
        <!--            android:enabled="false"-->
        <!--            android:exported="true"-->
        <!--            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"-->
        <!--            android:label="one 2"-->
        <!--            android:targetActivity=".MainActivity"-->
        <!--            tools:targetApi="34">-->

        <!--            &lt;!&ndash; intent filter &ndash;&gt;-->
        <!--            <intent-filter>-->
        <!--                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />-->

        <!--                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />-->
        <!--            </intent-filter>-->
        <!--        </activity-alias>-->


    </application>

</manifest>
```